# Failing to generate dynamic routes with Sapper export

Tags: svelte, sapper

I have a dynamic route:

`routes/artwork/[slug].svelte`.

All works great with `npm run dev`.

But when I `npm run export` those dynamic slug routes are missing. I don't see them in the `__sapper__/export`, and the pages are missing as well when I uploaded to Netlify.

Any clue how I might be able to fix that? Did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sapper export` works by building your app, running it, then visiting `/` and recursively visiting every internal link it finds. For that reason, it has to be possible to get to `/artwork/foo` and `/artwork/bar` etc by following links from the home page (e.g. via a `routes/artwork/index.svelte` page, which would map to `/artwork`).

Comment: Thanks Rich. I suppose that the problem is that i don't use `routes/artwork/index.svelte` just `routes/artwork/[slug].svelte`. Is that not possible?

Comment: To be clear each one of my page uses a `Feed` component which then has links to `artwork/{slug}`. So i was thinking `export` would crawl those pages (clearly they exist) for those dynamic links, but is in the case that I need a link on my home page directly to `/artwork`? Thanks again.

Comment: It doesn't need to be *direct*, but yeah, you would need a link *somewhere* that was accessible via the homepage. (It doesn't need to be a visible link, if you don't want it in the nav etc — `<a hidden href="artwork">Artwork</a>` would also work fine)

Comment: Oh, i found the root cause of the problem. I have a `TransitionWrapper` component wrapping each page and it has a `{#if show}` which is `false` to start and is flipped to `true` on mount. This was to allow for a fade transition when first loading the page. I'll have to work around that, but just to confirm that `export` actually works the way I had it originally with links inside my `Feed` component. Thanks again for your time, Rich, I'm a huge believer in Svelte!

Comment: so just to conclude if anybody comes across this: I added a hidden to link to the `artwork` page in my navbar. The artwork page doesn't make use of the `TransitionWrapper` (which doesn't matter since it's hidden anyway). And all my dynamic links are generated with `npm export`

Answer (score 0):

To add additional context to [Rich Harris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58505869/6501141):

If a similar route URL is crawled incorrectly before the dynamic routes are, it won't try to generate the dynamic route.

A homepage link uses `"/events/slug"` instead of `href="events/slug"`, the dev site will correctly provide a 404 on the homepage link, and serve the dynamic slugs on the events page. But, on build, the slugs will not be generated at all.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [collardeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3648524/collardeau) in my case the problem was that I wrapped my page components in a `TransitionWrapper` component that has `{#if show}` which is `false` to start and is flipped to `true` on mount. A simple workaround was starting it with `true` then flip it twice on mount:

```js
// TransitionWrapper.svelte
...
let show = true;

onMount(() => {
    show = false;
    show = true;
});
...
```

Since the code is executed inside onMount, it works without any issues based on the tests I've run

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is have this issue. The solution above didn't really help cause **I have lots of nested routes** and you can't specify those routes using the `--entries` approach.

However what worked was creating a `404.svelte` file in my `routes` folder and then adding this to my `package.json`

```
"export": "sapper export --legacy --entry \"/ /404\"",
"postexport": "mv __sapper__/export/404/index.html __sapper__/export/404.html",
```

The source of this solution was from this [github issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/557)