# Routing doesn't work after deploying a Svelte Sapper export

Tags: url-routing, svelte, sapper

I uploaded the export directory of a Svelte app using Sapper to example.com. In the */routes* directory I created a page called *foo.svelte*. When I click on a link in the app that forwards me to */foo*, I see that page, both locally and on example.com.

But when I go to *example.com/foo* directly in the browser, I get a 404. Understandable, because nothing is hosted on that address.

So what do I need to change on example.com so that the routing works not just from within the app, but also by typing in the URL directly in the address bar of the browser?

The site runs on Apache and I have Plesk as management tool.

Comment: Duplicate question. A friend just found this link for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669323/redirect-a-non-existing-url-to-error-page

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58501974/failing-to-generate-dynamic-routes-with-sapper-export